# I have come across a formula =SUMIFS(V2:Z2,L2:P2,">"&0)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I get the sum range is from V2 to Z2 but unable to get the criteria. Please help.
What does ">" mean without any variable and then adding &0.

Please guys explain in detail.

Comment: It will sum all the values greater than zero (0).

Comment: So it will add V2:Z2 if any block from L2:P2 is greater than zero right?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `">"&0` is the following:

`&` is the concatenation operator:

`="Hello" & " " & "Dolly"` reveals "Hello Dolly".

It also works with numbers:

`="I am " & 48 & " years old."` reveals "I am 48 years old."

So, `">"&0` is the concatenation of ">" and 0, or: ">0". This then being the criteria for the `SumIFS()` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What Dominique said, and just to add you could use ">0" without the '&' , unless you wanted to replace the 0 with a cell  reference.

It's a bit odd that the ranges are not consistent / aligned.
It still works ( so long as each range is the same length )  - but is unorthodox!

```
':: Your original - simplified.. 
':: Sum cells V2 > Z2  where L2>P2  are greater than zero. 
=SUMIFS(V2:Z2,L2:P2,">0")

':: Modified to reference a fixed cell
':: Sum cells V2 > Z2  where L2>P2  are greater than cell $A$2
=SUMIFS(V2:Z2,L2:P2,">"&$A$2)
```